# Are you able to add pojo fact classes to a kiebase in drools?

Tags: java, drools

If you can add pojos to a kiebase, how would you go about retrieving them?  I want to associate my rule drl files with their corresponding fact classes under the same package in the maven repo.   I would like to dynamically get the kiebase from a repo, get the classes, instantiate them with input data, then feed them into the generated kiesession.  If this is not possible, can someone propose another way?

Comment: I think you're asking if you can publish your java classes in a kjar, right? As written your questions really doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I have fact classes which I would like to publish alongside my drl files.  Is this possible when you define a kmodule?

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the ["declared types"](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.52.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#drl-declarations-con_drl-rules) functionality, you can get the KBase defined classes using the reflection API, see an example [here](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/88e4ab47fe173739866a3a54c22c5ddfb04bf0fe/drools-model/drools-model-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/modelcompiler/DeclaredTypesTest.java#L81). It's probably a bad idea, but without knowing what you want to do it's hard to decide.